# Spring MockMVC inject mockHttpServletRequest when not in method signature

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, mocking, integration-testing

Given I have inherited some Spring MVC controller code with signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

  String remoteAddress = request.getRemotedAddr();
  auditService.logAddress(remoteAddress);

  // do work...

  return mav;
}
```

and I have a Spring MockMvc test that performs the test

```
public void someTest() {
    mockMvc().perform(fileUpload("/upload").file(FileFactory.stringContent("myFile")));

    // do work...
    verify(auditService.logAddress("123456"));
}
```

I need to set the remote address to "12345" on the HttpServletRequest object that is passed into my upload controller method, so I can verify the call to mock **auditService** in the test.

I can create a **MockHttpServletRequest** object and call the **setRemoteAddr()** method, but how to pass this mock request object to the mockMvc() method call?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can add a [`RequestPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/RequestPostProcessor.html). Which you can then pass in to the mockmvc stuff by using the `with()` method.

```
mockMvc().perform(
  fileUpload("/upload")
  .file(FileFactory.stringContent("myFile"))
  .with(new RequestPostProcessor() { 
    public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
       request.setRemoteAddr("12345"); 
       return request;
    }}));
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: I tried this, but request.getRemoteAddr() returns 127.0.0.1 which I think is the default behaviour. :(

Comment: Not if the `setRemoteAddr` is called. So there must be something wrong with your solution/setup/testcode...

Comment: Definitely works. And now you can use a Java 8 lambda to do it.