# How to set role in MockHttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test

I have read following topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487953/2674303

But it is a bit not my variant.

Inside my method controller which I need to test I have following line:

```
httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("ROLE_OWNER");
```

How can I set role in `MockHttpServletRequest` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 mockMvc.perform(post("/owner/terminals/edit").principal(principal).with(new RequestPostProcessor() {
            public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
                request.addUserRole("ROLE_OWNER");
                return request;
            }
```

Comment: what is the `principal` in this case?